# Android Studio, how to find view width and height. getWidth() returned 0

Tags: android

I followed the thread answered by Gautier Haroun on how to create a touchscreen and allow tapping and displaying the coordinate. But I want to normalize the coordinate by dividing with the `text view` width and height respectively to get a range between `0~1`.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        // this is the view on which you will listen for touch events
        final View touchView = findViewById(R.id.touchView);
        final float touchWidth = touchView.getWidth();
        final float touchHeight = touchView.getHeight();

        touchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {    
                textView.setText("Touch coordinates : " +
                        String.valueOf(event.getX()/touchWidth) + " x " + String.valueOf(event.getY()/touchHeight));
                return true;
            }
        });


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Then the layout:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World, TestActivity"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/touchView"
    android:background="#f00"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:alpha="0.5" />
```

I tried final float `touchWidth = touchView.getWidth();`
But the result is infinite, so touch Width is 0 instead of around 1500 in my case. Can you tell me how to get the width and height of the View object touch View?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
touchView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                touchView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
            else {
                touchView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }

            final float touchWidth = touchView.getWidth();
            final float touchHeight = touchView.getHeight();
            ...
        }
    });
```

your code will look like this:

```
private float touchWidth;
private float touchHeight;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    final TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    // this is the view on which you will listen for touch events
    final View touchView = findViewById(R.id.touchView);

    touchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { 
            if(touchWidth == 0 || touchHeight == 0)
                return false;

            textView.setText("Touch coordinates : " +
                    String.valueOf(event.getX()/touchWidth) + " x " + String.valueOf(event.getY()/touchHeight));
            return true;
        }
    });

    touchView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                touchView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
            else {
                touchView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }

            touchWidth = touchView.getWidth();
            touchHeight = touchView.getHeight();
        }
    });

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. But I am not sure how I can return touchWidth and touchHeight and pass them to the touchWidth and touchHeight in onCreate().

Comment: simply declare `touchWidth` and `touchHeight` variables as global in your class, see my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

[OnGlobalLayoutListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html) is one method for getting the measurement

```
ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = view.getViewTreeObserver();
      if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
      viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
               view.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
          } else {
               view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
          }
          viewWidth = view.getWidth();
          viewHeight = view.getHeight();
        }
      });
    }
```

The another method is use `onWindowFocusChanged`

```
 @Override
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
  super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
  viewWidth = view.getWidth();
  viewHeight = view.getHeight();
 }
```

Comment: be careful that `removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this)` works starting SDK 16 (4.1 jelly bean) only